# How to pass data after clicking an image using PHP post?

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have this html code for an image:

```
<a href"hurr.php" onclick="post"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a>
```

I also have other images on the same page that also link to hurr.php. What I want to do is for hurr.php to be a custom page that displays information based on which image was clicked to get to the page. So, for example, I would use the php echo function to display img1.png rather than img2.png.

Is the code I have for the image right, and what code do I need to display on hurr.php in order to display custom information on each image? I want to use 'post' for this.

Comment: Missing an `=` after `href` or typo? And you can redirect to _hurr.php_ onclick passing the image name as GET Parameter, but if you want to use POST, you can do it through AJAX or at least you need javascript for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is two way of doing this, if you have to use POST variable then you need to use AJAX,
or you can send the GET variable.

```
<a href="hurr.php?myVar=someValue" onclick="post"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a>
```

In hurr.php

you can get the variable by either `$_GET['myVar']` or `$_REQUEST['myVar']`

Answer (score 3):

```
<a href="#" onclick="document.form_name.image_name.value = 'img1.png'; document.form_name.submit(); return false;"><img src="images/img1.png"/></a>
<form id="form_name" name="form_name" action="hurr.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" id="image_name" name="image_name" value="" />
</form>
```